# Animate scroll jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

So I think I might have an idea of what my problem is -- in an effort to make my site responsive, I've used `height:auto` and set height using `min-height:some-percentage`. I understand this might not be best practice but it works and is a lot less time consuming than media queries.

So the following code for animated scroll used to work when I didn't set height using the method stated above:

```
$('.animate_scroll').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //I tried without this line
    var loc_id = $($(this).attr('href')),
        loc_pos = loc_id.offset().top;
    console.log($(this).attr('href')); //outputs the right div id
    console.log(loc_pos); //outputs offset greater than 0
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : loc_pos}, 300)
})
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The reason I said I think I have an idea of what my problem is is because the `console.log` statements above log valid values.

**Update**:
In the code above, I've added a couple more console.log statements to get offset values. The values are different but even if I set loc_id to `document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('id')).offsetTop` then use that as my scrollTop value, it doesn't scroll.

```
console.log($(this).attr('href')); //correct id
console.log(loc_pos); //outputs 794.546875
console.log(document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('id')).offsetTop); //944
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q8e6h9tv/)

```js
 $(".jumper").on("click", function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("body, html").animate({ 
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
        }, 2000);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pliip">pliip</div><a class="jumper" href="#ploop">Ploop</a><a id="#a_id">LINK TO MOVE</a>
<div style="height:1000px;background-color:#666">div</div>
<!-- Landing elements -->
<a class="jumper" href="#pliip">Pliip</a>
<div id="ploop">ploop</div>
```

Comment: hmmm I've tried the `<a>` tag before and unfortunately it doesn't work :/ If I'm not mistaken, the offset value is stated in `px`? If so, I think that is my problem. The offset value logged to console is around 700 when clearly the sum of all the element heights in `px` before the scroll destination is greater.